# How to remove birthdays from iCal?

Tags: macos, ical

Does anyone know how to do this? I already unchecked birthdays in the iCal > preferences

[image]

[image]

I am the Admin
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to unsubscribe from birthdays in Google calendar in order to remove it from iCal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's Google Calendar! Just uncheck birthday updates. And make sure you apply this to ALL of your Google accounts, school, default accounts, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the birthday in Address Book.  Any birthdays in Address Book automatically show up in Calendar.  If you click on the birthday and press the delete key it should pop up a box telling you this.